# Exporting Out-of-box-drivers from MDT 2010 into a new install of MDT 2010

Tags: mdt-2010

I am currently trying to setup a new instance of MDT 2010 and would like to export my Out of box Drivers from the current MDT solution we have, into the new one.  I tried simply copying the contents of the folder over but the drivers don't show up in the snap-in.  Is there a way to export them from my "old" system and into the "new" system, without having to manually import the drivers all over again?  I know I can setup up a Link Deployment, but I'm hesitant to do this as I don't want to accidentally overwrite the new MDT setup which is working perfectly (except for missing those drivers).  I just need the drivers really, I've changed the way everything else works on the new system.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that might be a problem, as when one imports drivers into MDT and update the deployment share, it will update the physical .WIM file and associated .XML file to register the drivers. Apart from editing the .WIM file and associated .XML file I tink the easiet way would be to copy that folder over and just import the whole lot in one go, ater which yuo can re-organise into categories and selection profiles.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done by connecting to 2 deployment shares and dragging and dropping the "folders" from one share to the other. I have done this often and it works just fine. It does however take some time.